# Hilbert transform of a Gaussian wave packet

Tags: integral-transforms

For the following function $f$, function from real number to real number, with $\mu$ real, $k$ real, $\sigma$ real strictly positif, defined by:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=cos(k x ) e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\end{equation}
The Hilbert transformation $\mathcal{H}$ is defined by:
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle [\mathcal{H}(g)](x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \text{p.v.} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{g(t)}{x - t} ~ d{x} 
\end{equation}

What is the expression of $H(f)(x)$?

Comment: Hint: try using that the Hilbert transform is a Fourier multiplier.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Is what you advise working on $\mathcal{F}^{-1}.(−\imath~sign(k)).\mathcal{F}.f$?

Comment: Yes exactly that.